# How to get array from Firestore and loop through it in Android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get a field called **services** which is an array of Strings from the Firestore document.

I am doing it like this:

```
    fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    fStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    
      fAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(Etemail.getText().toString(), Etpassword.getText().toString()).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
  
                        Uid = authResult.getUser().getUid();
                        checkUserAccessLevel(Uid);
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                
                 private void checkUserAccessLevel(String uid) {
                 
                 DocumentReference df = fStore.collection("Users").document(uid);

                df.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                List<String> services = new ArrayList<>();
                DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                if (document.exists()) {
                    Map<String, Object> map = document.getData();
                    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                        services.add(entry.getValue().toString());
                    }
                    Log.d(TAG, services.toString());
                    
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException()); 
            }
        }

    });
                 
}
```

This is the screenshot of Firebase Firestore DB!

[image]

Please help me to achieve the task.

Comment: You haven't actually said what's wrong with the code you've provided. Make sure you post your desired output, what you actually got, any crashes etc.

Answer (score 1):

To get the values that exist within your "services" array, you need to read the content of the document. Remember that DocumentSnapshot's [getData()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot#getData()) method, returns a Map<String, Object> that can be simply iterated, as the following lines of code:

```
FirebaseFirestore fStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
DocumentReference df = fStore.collection("Users").document(uid);
df.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            List<String> services = new ArrayList<>();
            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
            if (document.exists()) {
                Map<String, Object> map = document.getData();
                for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                    services.add(entry.getValue().toString());
                }
                Log.d(TAG, services.toString());
                //Do what you need to do with your services List
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

The result in the logcat will be:

```
[Cardiology, Oncology, Neurology, Urology]
```

Comment: Hey Alex, thanks for your reply and time. In the logcat its showing full collection like this [Person Name, 9864#####, [Cardiology, Oncology, Neurology, Urology], 1, xyz@gmail.com, [09:00 to 10:00, 10:00 to 11:00, 11:00 to 12:00, 12:00 to 13:00]] i just wanted the array of services like => [Cardiology, Oncology, Neurology, Urology] any workaround for this?

Comment: This is the json object struction i am getting from the firestore:  {FullName=XYZ JKL, PhoneNumber=9865#####, services=[Cardiology, Oncology, Neurology, Urology], isAdmin=1, UserEmail=abc@gmail.com, time_slot=[09:00 to 10:00, 10:00 to 11:00, 11:00 to 12:00, 12:00 to 13:00]}

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code that you are using **now** and produces that output.

Comment: I have edited the code of the post, please check it. This is the code after applying the patch provided by you.

Comment: The Log statement that produces that message comes certainly from another place of the code that is right now shared. It might be related to what is inside "checkUserAccessLevel(Uid)". Just a guess. I just run the code I provided you using the exact database schema and it works 100% fine. Can you confirm that after you check again?

Comment: OK, let me check it again.

Comment: @SwapnilLanjewar getData() method returns all data from document. If you only want services array you can get it like: Map<String, Object> map = document.getData(); List<String> services = (List<String>) map.get("services");

Comment: Yes, I checked it again its the code provided by you Sir.

Comment: @AlexMamo i tried and got that array without problem.

Comment: @SwapnilLanjewar So you say that when you that you try to log "services", which is a List, using this line `Log.d(TAG, services.toString());`, you are getting the following output "Person Name, 9864#####, [Cardiology, Oncology, Neurology, Urology], 1, xyz@gmail.com", right? But how about if you change that line to "Log.d(TAG, "size: " + services.size());" are you getting `size: 4`, which is correct right? As you have only 4 elements.

Comment: Yes you are right, Alex! The size of array is 4.

Comment: So certainly then `Log.d(TAG, services.toString());` will print those 4 values "[Cardiology, Oncology, Neurology, Urology]" and nothing more. As the "services" is an array with only 4 String objects, right?

Comment: @AlexMamo i got the array of services by map.put("services", document.get("services")); but its in (key, value) pair and I want to iterate through the array so that I can display it in an activity but if I do List<String> services = new ArrayList<>(); services.add(map.get("services").toString()); its giving me:  [[Cardiology, Oncology, Neurology, Urology]] what should I do to get each element from the array.

Comment: Iterate once again, or simply use my answer. You just said that `Log.d(TAG, services.toString());` prints those 4 values "[Cardiology, Oncology, Neurology, Urology]", what is wrong then?

Answer (score 0):

You can use either `get()` method or `getData()` method.

- `get()`  method takes a `String` parameter (field name - note the there are also different versions of this method) and returns `Object` and you need to caste to your data type. You can use it for a single field (or more fields) if you don't want to get whole data from document as a `Map<String, Object>`.
- `getData()` method returns whole data from document as `Map<String, Object>`. `String`  is the document's fields names and `Object` is the data belongs to that fields. With your field name (or names) you can get the data belong to that field (or fields). Also you need to cast to your data type.

Get data according to the field name with using `get()` method:

```
 df.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                        List<String> services = new ArrayList<>(),
                                timeSlot = new ArrayList<>();
                        if (document.exists()) {
                            services = (List<String>) document.get("services");
                            timeSlot = (List<String>) document.get("time_slot");
                        } else {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Document is not exist");
                        }
                    }else{
                        Log.e(TAG, "Task Failed: " + task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });
```

Get all data with `getData()` method and get your field values with using fields' names:

```
df.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                        List<String> services = new ArrayList<>(),
                                timeSlot = new ArrayList<>();
                        if (document.exists()) {
                            Map<String, Object> data = document.getData();
                            services = (List<String>) data.get("services");
                            timeSlot = (List<String>) data.get("time_slot");
                        } else {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Document is not exist");
                        }
                    }else{
                        Log.e(TAG, "Task Failed: " + task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });
```